# AutoHotKey: How to find out if a certain window has or hasn't been interacted with

Tags: autohotkey

I'm making an AutoHotKey script which closes down a window if certain conditions have been met.

At first, my task was to set it to close the window if the computer hadn't been interacted with in, say, 5 minutes. AutoHotKey provides a variable that checks if there has been any interaction with the computer from the user, and that variable is `A_TimeIdle`. It updates every time the user interacts with the computer, to 0, and then increases obviously as the user doesn't interact with the computer.

What I need now something like `A_TimeIdle`, but for the user interacting with a specific window rather than the entire computer. Does autohotkey provide anything like that? Any way to check how long a window has been inactive for, something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, check_for_window
return

    check_for_window:
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class Notepad
{
    Tooltip
    return
}
IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
{
    SetTimer, check_for_window, off
    Tooltip
    WinWaitNotActive, ahk_class Notepad
    SetTimer, time_window_has_been_inactive
}
return

    time_window_has_been_inactive:
Loop 60
{
    Sleep 100
    IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
        return
}
SetTimer, time_window_has_been_inactive, off
IfWinExist, ahk_class Notepad
{
    Tooltip, Notepad has been inactive for 6 seconds
    ; do sth
}
SetTimer, check_for_window, on
return
```

See also:
[Minimize Inactive Windows](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/8603-minimize-inactive-windows/)

Answer (score -1):

Use IfWinExist command.

Maybe you don't know if the window is comming up or not so I suggest you to insert into a loop to try it various times.

```
i:=0
while(i < 5){
   IfWinExist, "Title"
   i := i + 1
   Sleep, 200 ;Wait a bit for the next comparison
}
```

Another useful command is WinWait. You can check the definition here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm

IfWinExist: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm